# Hi, I have a dataset containing N number of records and i am trying to read each 100 records from dataset until it finish count

Tags: c#, dataset

I have a dataset containing N number of records and i am trying to read each 100 records from dataset to loop through and save them until it reaches the total count N in C#. Couldn't get through this and looking for help or advice on how to dot his..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have untyped `DataSet`:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
//filling dataset
var rows = ds.Tables["myTable"].Rows.OfType<DataRow>().ToList();
var size = rows.Count;
var position = 0;
var chunkSize = 100;
while (position < size)
{
    var chunk = rows.Skip(position).Take(chunkSize);
    position += chunkSize;
}
```

Comment: @Sam if this is solution to your question, you should accept the answer